# problem in running app engine application

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I created an application to add an event into my Google Calendar. I ran it successfully and added an event in my calendar. After that I deployed my application into Google App Engine and ran my program in a browser. It accepts input but doesn't add the event into the calendar. I don't know what the problem is. How do I solve this?

Comment: you need to look at your logs for errors. If there is nothing, you need to add more logging code to your application to see what is going on. Make sure you never ignore exceptions or return codes.

Comment: what is mean for logging code

Comment: `log.debug("now I am here, doing this, with this data: "+x)`

Comment: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#Logging